# Location management and the new apis

Tags: android, android-location

I have an application that was near to release that I have recently gone back to, it uses the traditional method of locationlisteners and registering receivers instead of the new version which uses Googles new low energy consumption location tracking.

Should I move over to the GooglePlay location management? Are there any downsides to using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the new version which uses Googles new low energy consumption location tracking.

I would phrase it as "lower", not "low".

> Are there any downsides to using it?

It introduces a dependency upon Play Services, which means that your app cannot be used on devices that lack it, such as the Kindle Fire.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there a compromise that can be had? Devices that have the access can use it and others that don't can default back to the standard way?

Comment: @JamieB: Part of using `LocationClient` is to check to see if the device has Play Services support. For devices that lack it, you could fall back to `LocationManager`-based approaches. However, that requires double the code for location logic. You will have to judge for yourself whether you think the fused location provider is worth coding this optimization.